# How to extract text field with css using Xpath

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract price from html using the below xpath expression.

```
<div class="-hr -pvs -mtxs" data-prd-prices="">
    ::before
    <span dir="ltr" data-price="" class="-b -ltr -tal -fs24">₦ 3,550</span>

</div>
```

`my_xpath = //div[@class='-hr -pvs -mtxs']/span/text()`

The xpath expression locates the price but when I try to scrape the price I get this

```
 [<Selector xpath="//div[@class='-hr -pvs -mtxs']/span/text()" data='₦ 3,550'>]
```

I know that this is coming from the **::before** in the html tag. what does that mean and how can I extract the price

when I hover the  **::before** in the chrome developer tool I get this

```
div.-hr -pvs -mtxs::before
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done the right thing but you are not extracting the data.

```
my_xpath = "//div[@class='-hr -pvs -mtxs']/span/text()"
extracted_data = response.xpath(my_xpath).getall()
```

should do the job.